# convert seconds to H:M:S with "efficiency"

Tags: java

I had to convert seconds to H:M:S, and it was worth 30 points in an exam, however I was docked 3 points for "efficiency". Why?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class secToMin{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int sec, secTotal, hour, min, rem;
        secTotal = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of seconds"));
        if (secTotal<0) 
        {   
            System.out.println("invalid input");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        hour = (secTotal/3600);
        rem = (secTotal%3600);
        min = (rem/60);
        sec = (rem%60);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, secTotal + " equals " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ".");  

        System.exit(0);             
    }
}
```

Comment: minutes = secTotal/60; seconds = secTotal % 60;

Comment: First, you do not calculate the minutes but the hour, minutes and seconds, is that normal?

Comment: OT: The first letter of a classname is usually uppercase.

Comment: @DV88 I guess that could be it, but shouldnt that be min=hours/60, since secTotal/60 would give me more hours instead of any minutes?

Comment: From the seconds, calculate the minutes.  From the minutes, calculate the hours.

Answer (score 0):

The potentially intended solution for the exam may have been to avoid magic numbers like "3600" (OK, it's a well known value, yet, it's a large value).

Instead, [Units of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_time) in the [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) as defined by [the National Institute of Standards and Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology) will simply tell you that an hour is "60 minutes" and a minute is "60 seconds".

You can achieve the same conversion steps with:

```
min = secTotal / 60;
hour = min / 60;
min = min % 60;
sec = secTotal % 60;
```